# Is there a Python function to remove characters in text?

Tags: python

I have a text that there is an open and close parenthesis and in this text there is a parenthesis that is open and not close and open but not close so I need to remove that is open and not close and open but not close and replace it with "!error". How can I do ???

```
Text_To_Correct = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, (consectetur) adipiscing elit. Nunc) fringilla metus eget) elit tristique (dignissim.
                     Mauris id nisi (et tortor fringilla tincidunt) sed sit amet elit. Aliquam feugiat velit sollicitudin, tempor velit et,
                     maximus sem. Etiam (varius tincidunt est. Proin (mattis convallis) tincidunt phasellus euismod tortor eget
                     vestibulum sollicitudin, mi lorem eleifend libero, non consequat sem velit in elit. Ut nisi felis, lacinia nec elit
                     non, lacinia rutrum urna. Quisque (vitae sagittis) diam, ut lobortis nisi. Maecenas id massa velit phasellus et
                     massa laoreet, maximus diam aliquam, ) accumsan elit."""


Remove_Close_Parenthesis= Text_To_Correct.replace(")", " !error ")

Remove_Open_Parenthesis= Remove_Close_Parenthesis.replace("(","!error")



print(Remove_Open_Parenthesis)
```

I figured out that all parenthesis are removed.

Comment: you can use a simple `replace` or `re.sub`

Comment: Why do you keep saying "open and not close and open but not close"?

Comment: string is immutable. you can replace word with another, by using `replace` method. but it will affect all the word containing in that string.

Comment: Do you want to bracket count and show any syntax errors and the position or just simple replacements?

Comment: They're saying they want it to put "!error" if there is an incomplete set of parenthesis. Such as the `fringilla metus eget)` area.

Comment: Are nested like `((text) (text))` OK?, or simply `(text) (text)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing correct () pairs with [] (any delimiter) and remaining with !error and undo the first step

```
r=Text_To_Correct
r= re.sub(r'\(([^()]*?)\)',r'[\1]',r)
r= re.sub(r'\(|\)',r'!error',r)
r= re.sub(r'\[([^\[\]]*?)\]',r'(\1)',r)
```

For nested ()

```
r=Text_To_Correct
pattern=r'\(([^()]*?)\)'
while re.search(pattern,r):
    r= re.sub(pattern,r'[\1]',r)
r= re.sub(r'\(|\)',r'!error',r)
pattern2=r'\[([^\[\]]*?)\]'
while re.search(pattern2,r):
    r= re.sub(pattern2,r'(\1)',r)
```

Comment: Thank you very much it's working even if I don't complain can you give some explication please